# Reading postgres NOTICE message in C++ API

Tags: postgresql

I am struggling to read my Postgres `NOTICE` messages in my C++ API. I can only read `EXCEPTION`messages using the function `PQresultErrorMessage(PGresult)`, but not lower level messages.

`PQresultErrorField(res, PG_DIAG_SEVERITY) returns null pointer.`

How do I read `NOTICE` and other low level messages?

(Using PostgreSQL 9.2)

Answer (score 0):

Set up a notice receiver or notice processor using `PQsetNoticeReceiver` / `PQsetNoticeProcessor`. Both set up callbacks that are invoked when asynchronous notifications are received. Note that this may happen before, during, or after processing of query data.

It's safe to assume that after all query results are returned (`PQexec` or whatever has returned) and you've called `PQconsumeInput` to make sure there's nothing else waiting, then all notices for the last command are received. The `PQconsumeInput` shouldn't really be necessary, it's just to be cautious.

See [the documentation for libpq](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-notice-processing.html).